# Is possible to receive push notification in First in First out order from GCM?

Tags: android, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have developed an app using GCM for push notification.My app using for stacking purpose so I have to receive notification like in First in First out order.But now am not getting notification from GCM in order.How to manage to receive notification in order and is possible to manage GCM server from our end.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible in GCM server. But another way is you can Hack this Notification in your Server triggered by GCM and Run a cron at particular order.

Comment: please can u give steps to run a cron at particular order

Answer (score 1):

no you cannot get the notification in first in first out order .they are randomly generated by the server.you can do this in your server connected with  GCM  and put them in serial order

Answer (score 0):

gcm document already mention this

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html

> Note that the order of delivery is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

GCM order of message is not guaranteed. For this you can achieve another way.

Ask to server guys to create API(Webserver) for message, The message is same as they were earlier sending through the GCM.

After that you have to create Calender scheduler (Like Every 5 min) and then call this web-service and show notification.